# Logo has strange boldness in 'N' characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The logo for the web site, both meta and regular, has the N characters' vertical lines somehow bolder than everything else.

Here's how it renders on my browser:

[image: fat N's]

The lines are two pixel columns wide, both columns fully saturated. No other letters are affected AFAICT.

The strange thing is, I'm looking at [sprites.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/japanese/img/sprites.png?v=d858ccbb952d) in an image editor, and I cannot locate the same boldness. One column of pixels is with full opacity and the other one isn't.

It's like my browser can't handle PNG transparency for that single letter. (Welcome to 1999?)

Anyone else seeing the same?

I'm on **Seamonkey 2.39, FreeBSD 9.3 amd64**. (No reproduce on SM 2.40/Win2k3 on the same computer.)

Reproduced on a different computer; on both **Opera 12.18** and **MSIE11,** **Windows 8.1.**

Comment: I'm not seeing the same thing. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Note that there are two background images specified for the sprites in the CSS: PNG and SVG. The SVG comes later so it overrides the PNG as long as your browser supports it. I'm not surprised there is some odd rendering bug with the SVG...

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. Fix has been pushed to repo and waiting for build. It shouldn't take longer than 24h. I will keep an eye on that.

Comment: Not sure if this is a fix, but at the moment it looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sa0dx.png

Comment: If there are problems with the font, we could always [change it](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1580/1628).

Comment: Yeah, same kind of N for me too. Looks cool though, sort of.

Answer (score 12):

Having quite the opposite - missing lines in N letters:

[image: Missing lines in N letters]

Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome `Version 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit)`

Comment: Also, if I open [sprites.svg](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/japanesemeta/img/sprites.svg), I see the same even when I zoom in.

Comment: You're looking at Paweł's fixed version. The fix was defective, of course.

Comment: Oh, I see. Should have read the comments =)

Comment: I'm having the missing lines too

Comment: Welcome to JAPA\ESE LA\GUAGE Stack Exchange!

Comment: I have the same, Vivaldi on Windows 10. I didn't have any problems when I first saw this question.

Comment: whoops! i'm not sure how this issue sneaked in, but fix is coming!

Comment: can anyone confirm it's fixed?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed, looks perfect! Thank you.